# Algebraic groups?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I have been doing group theory lately but I can not seem to find what I am looking for online (partly because I am not entirely sure what I am looking for).

An example of one of the questions:

If group $S$ is defined as positive real numbers $a$ and $b$ find the identity. 
and then it shows the operation $a \circ b = 4ab^2$

I sort of understand the whole identity part but what I am having trouble with is the "operation". I just want to know if $a \circ b = 4ab^2$ simply means that you have any two numbers from the group and those would sub into the a and be. I know that you don't ever actually get the numbers.

What I am trying to ask is are $a$ and $b$ merely the inputs and the $4ab^2$ is the actual equation or something? If someone could help explain and maybe give me some websites with information about this I would be very grateful.

Comment: Go back and read again the definition of a group, it will certainly help you to answer this yourself. The first line of the wiki page on groups pretty much answers what you are asking

Comment: The book I am using doesn't actually define a group it just seems to assume that you understand it all (It is a really bad book). The wording is awful and it has no examples either, a complete waste of money really

Comment: Use more than one source of information if you find the book is not satisfactory. What book is it, may I ask? Also if you are just self learning, you will probably be able to find lecture notes on introductions to group theory online for free. They will be tailored to a new undergrad so will often be easy to follow. Beware of different people using different notation though, that is something you should always be wary of when reading.

Comment: That's the problem, I can't find a good website because I don't even know what this called all I know is that it uses groups and when I go to websites about groups it is always just explaining the rules and doesn't use the notation I am looking for. It's a Maths Quest Maths C book. So just a textbook

Comment: Here are a set of lecture notes I have found by a quick search 

http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~jim/F13YR1/Notes.pdf

The author uses $*$ instead of $\circ$ in their notation. Also if you havent looked at the wiki page here is the first sentence: "In mathematics, a group is an algebraic structure consisting of a set of elements together with an operation that combines any two elements to form a third element."

Comment: Thank you I just started reading that and already it is much better

Comment: BTW, you might want to consider a different title (though this one did draw me here :) ). An algebraic group is, slightly strangely but for historical reasons, a special type of group which has some geometry behind it (I think geometric group already had a different meaning when people started studying these).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question you are being asked, your scenario is the following:

---

(1) The set $S$ is your domain; in particularly, $S = \mathbb{R^+}$.

(2) The binary-operation you are working with is $a \circ b = 4ab^2$

(3) You are being asked to find the identity for this operation.

---

The difficulty is here is that you will not find an identity element for this binary-operation over this set. If you are to find (3), you must find an element $e \in \mathbb{R^+}$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R^+}(x \circ e = e \circ x = x)$. In this case, if you try to let $e = \dfrac{1}{2}$. Then $a \circ e = 4a(\dfrac{1}{2})^2 = \dfrac{4}{4}a = a$ you get the problem of $e \circ b = \dfrac{1}{2}b^2 \neq b$ (when $b \neq \sqrt{2}$).

So your the set of positive reals with the binary-operation you have defined will not form a group as there is no identity element.

The operation is not even associative for $a \circ (b \circ c) = 4a(4bc^2)^2; (a \circ b) \circ c = (4ab^2)c^2$ and clearly $\ \sim \forall (a,b,c)[4a(4bc^2)^2 \neq (4ab^2)c^2]$.

So there is no group-structure to be had in your scenario.

Comment: I apologise for that, the answer in the back of the book says 1/2 but they are wrong all the time (really bad book). So what about if a∘b = a + b - 1?
I am basically just trying to understand what the '∘' symbol means (thanks for including it too).

Comment: @MilesUbiquity with the operation $a\circ b=a+b-1$, the real number from a group with neutral element $1$. In fact, $x\mapsto x-1$ is a group isomorphism $(\mathbb R,\circ)\to(\mathbb R,+)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand what the arrow denotes. I don't know whether I am allowed ask anything here so sorry but is something like [R,∘] valid? And does a∘b = ????? mean that if all the rules are met that a∘b = ???? is a binary operation that is defined by someone else. So a∘b is like defining what ∘ actually does? Like defining what multiplication as a∘b = a + a (b number of times)?